# Tortoise SVN Post Hook Commit Error?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I working on project and commit my updated files using SVN. I got the following error,

[image]

Kindly advice on this issue with SVN.

Answer (score 2):

A default Subversion installation does not have any post-commit hooks installed. Someone (your system administrator?) installed a script on the server and the server can't connect to the specified ip.

Sorry, can't help here, you need to ask the owner of the repository to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having connectivity issues: `could not connect to server (http://192.9.200.10)`. Verify you can see your SVN server and try it again.

Comment: @AI G yes i knew that, how to fix this. kindly help me

Comment: Check the basics if you have access to the server; Is the server up? Is your SVN service running?

Comment: i have checkout the svn repo from client machine, when commit the code its reach svn but not post commit. i have put the code post-commit to other location.

Comment: Unless you have access to the server, you need the admin to debug it. Tobias has a good summation.